# Google Sheets conditional formatting if value in range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I have a sheet that had a number of timeslots where people can put their names.

I have a list of names that I want to highlight if their name is not in the array of timeslots.

I can't seem to get this to work with conditional formatting.

This is what I've managed to do, I want to match the Names in the names column with any value in the array:

[image]

Comment: row wise or whole wise?

Comment: @player0 what is whole wise?

Comment: @kishkin whole-wise like it will check names column no matter where those names in names column are located

Comment: Like `=(D1 <> "")*(IFERROR(MATCH(D1, B:B, 0), 0) = 0)*(IFERROR(MATCH(D1, C:C, 0), 0) = 0)`?

Comment: @kishkin more like: `=REGEXMATCH(D2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, B:B, C:C))`

Comment: @player0 this works, but I do not get why. It does matching for all the rows used for expressions, and if any is true, than it is true? And w/o `ARRAYFORMULA`. This is strange... Also `|` will be applied to the two chars on left and on the right of it, so values should be grouped (for example): `=REGEXMATCH(D2, "(?:^" & TEXTJOIN("$)|(?:^", 1, B:B, C:C) & "$)"))`. But this won't help if there are some special chars in values like `)` or `*` - unexpected results will emerge. :)

Answer (score 3):

> highlight if their name is not in the array of timeslots

row-wise:

```
=(B2<>D2)*(C2<>D2)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Any reason not to use `AND()`? Just curious.

Comment: @kishkin actually two: its longer and requires comma but if OP's locale is non-US then it won't work regardless that formula is technically correct, he will just need to use a semicolon instead of a comma. using multiplication works for all ppl regardless of locale settings

Comment: Thank you @player0 for the explanation!